# Problemas con remover una clase de css en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema. Tengo el siguiente código html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Aprendiendo javascript</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="./main.js"></script>
        <style>
            .enorme {
                font-size: 44px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="parrafo" class="bonitoParrafo">Hola qué tal!!!</p>
        <p id="parrafo2" class="bonitoParrafo">Hola qué tal!!!</p>
        <p id="parrafo3" class="feitoParrafo">Hola soy un feito parrafo!!!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y el siguiente script de JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log("La página ha cargado");
    
    // let parrafo = this.document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    let parrafos = this.document.getElementsByClassName('bonitoParrafo');

    for (const parrafo of parrafos) {
        parrafo.style.color = "red";
        parrafo.innerHTML = "Esto es un texto <strong>bonito</strong>";
        parrafo.classList.add('enorme');
        parrafo.classList.remove('bonitoParrafo');
    }
})
```

El problema es que cuando se ejecuta pone los estilos y el texto del innerHTML en el primer párrafo, así como añadir la clase enorme, pero en el segundo párrafo no hace nada. El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por qué hace este comportamiento. La segunda iteración del bucle for no la hace.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Pues porque en la primera iteración, encuentra al elemento con la clase `bonitoParrafo` en tu HTML y a ese elemento le agregas la clase `enorme`, pero como luego lo estás eliminando, en la segunda iteración no lo va a encontrar, por lo tanto en ese segundo ciclo no va a saber a qué elemento con la clase `bonitoParrafo` le va a agregar la clase `enorme`:

```
let parrafos = this.document.getElementsByClassName('bonitoParrafo');

for (const parrafo of parrafos) {
  parrafo.style.color = "red";
  parrafo.innerHTML = "Esto es un texto <strong>bonito</strong>";
  parrafo.classList.add('enorme');
  parrafo.classList.remove('bonitoParrafo'); // aquí lo eliminas.
}
```

Solo debes comentar esa línea, ejemplo:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log("La página ha cargado");

  // let parrafo = this.document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
  let parrafos = this.document.getElementsByClassName('bonitoParrafo');

  for (const parrafo of parrafos) {
    parrafo.style.color = "red";
    parrafo.innerHTML = "Esto es un texto <strong>bonito</strong>";
    parrafo.classList.add('enorme');
    // parrafo.classList.remove('bonitoParrafo');
  }
})
```

```css
.enorme {
  font-size: 44px;
}
```

```html
<p id="parrafo" class="bonitoParrafo">Hola qué tal!!!</p>
<p id="parrafo2" class="bonitoParrafo">Hola qué tal!!!</p>
<p id="parrafo3" class="feitoParrafo">Hola soy un feito parrafo!!!</p>
```